# Bind List<object> to button's commandparameter within data template

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datatemplate

I want to delete the respective object from the list, where the Delete button is clicked.
I have assigned CommandParameter="{Binding}" which returns me the object bound to the respective listbox item.

but i want to pass the RuleConditions object (ItemsSource="{Binding RuleConditions}") on the button click as the commandparameter and then remove object from the list and then rebind it to the ListBox control.

XAML code :

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="50"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Width="50"></TextBox>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RuleType}"
                   Width="85" Height="20" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OperatorValues}"
                   Width="85" Height="20" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                <Button Content="Delete"  Margin="5,5,5,5" Command="{Binding  DataContext.ButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">                    
                </Button>

                <Button Content="Add"  Margin="5,5,5,5" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="lbUsers" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding RuleConditions}"> 
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

please let me know incase of any insufficient information, thanks in advance

Comment: RuleConditions are already in DataContext where ButtonCommand exists so there is no need to pass it as well.

Comment: sounds like a plan. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: The problem statement is to pass the list of RuleConditions object (collection object which is binded to the listview) and the respective bound object to the ListBox item on Button's (Delete Buttons) click as command parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can do Like this

```
<ListBox Name="lbUsers" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding RuleConditions}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding RuleCondition,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

and create a `RuleCondition` Property in ViewModel.
then in `DataTemplate` do Like this

```
  <Button Content="Delete"  Margin="5,5,5,5" Command="{Binding  DataContext.ButtonCommand, ElementName=lbUsers}"/>
```

All You need to do is inside the Command You need to check the `RuleConditions` contains `RuleCondition` and remove `RuleCondition` from list.

Comment: hi Dinesh thnks for the reply, i tried using your approach but on the click of the Delete buttons command the parameter object is set as null

Comment: I do get it.. and yes i haven't set that..as i have done the changes to my application code as per your answer, with this method of yours should i expect the `parameter` object to be not null within the `Execute(object parameter)` method within my 'ICommand' implemented  (`RelayCommand`) class.

Comment: yes @yogaa. And you can simply execute the action which you have in RelayCommand.